# What was the most prestigious tournament in season 1?

Tags: league-of-legends, competitive-gaming

Since I got into League of Legends in Season 2, I'm wondering what was the most important tournament in season 1, and who won it?

Answer (score 2):

The dreamhack tournament was the season 1 championship and was by far the biggest/most important tournament of season 1. It was won by Fnatic.

Comment: Thank you :) I had no idea fnatic was that good last season!